Bulk export images of single vector overlaid on series of rasters in QGIS
I am using QGIS 3.34.6.
I have 54 clipped raster files (monthly satellite pasture observations) with a vector file (farm outline) overlaid. Raster layers follow yyyymm naming convention.
In order to make a gif showing the pasture change through time, I would like to save the canvas as an image, named for the raster naming convention, for each of the 54 rasters. I would also like a label to show the active raster name on the exported image.
I have tried using the Atlas function to do it as a batch, but that isn't really Atlas's function and I can't make it work in this manner. Is there a way to export the layout as an image, change the active raster, export the image, change the raster, export, etc.?
If/when I sort this out, I would like to replicate the whole exercise for 250 farms, which will likely necessitate using Atlas - I'm comfortable I can make that work in due course.
Is there a function I've overlooked here? I am not Python literate but will gladly give it a go if someone can dump a code for me to put into place.
Cheers - James
